# How can I get the current running programs in java?

Tags: java, windows

I want to build a program, which can log the programs or threads running in windows. I would like to write the program in java.

Does anyone know such mehtod?

Comment: There is one already it is called process manager
Or ps in linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
        (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
  BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

run "`tasklist`" cmd using `runtime` instance.